# Require a gem library

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm kinda new to ruby and I'd like to use a gem charting library, but for some reason when I require it in the ruby script on my desktop it doesn't work. However when I `require` in my irb it does work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: nevermind I think I got it. I need to require rubygems before that. Out of curiosity, is there a reason why I need to do this?

Comment: Rubygems itself is a library that handles dependency resolution, so you need to include it in your scripts to take advantage of it. I would echo @tadman's sentiment below and recommend [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) and [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) for dependency management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) if you can and declare the requirements in a `Gemfile`. This will make your environment much more consistent between different computers and will provide a reference of the dependencies you have.

The Bundler setup procedure is pretty simple and well documented. It will load in all the gems and any of their dependencies automatically.

Generally the problem with the `require` statement failing is the library is not in your `$LOAD_PATH`, and that's usually because you haven't loaded `rubygems`:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'somegem'
require 'somegem'
```